# Learning resources for 'Guide for the Perplexed' by Rabbi Moshe Maimonides

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, english

I'm looking for some English resources on learning the 'Guide for the Perplexed' by Rabbi Moshe Maimonides. Unfortunately most resources are very heavy and not for bedtime reading. Im looking for an english translation or english commentary. Can anyone suggest something good?

Comment: I'm not sure the work was intended for bedtime reading

Comment: I second that. This is not a book that can simply be read, it must be studied. You should speak to someone who has studied the book for some time to get an idea of what kind of investment is required on your part to properly understand the book. Again, my opinion is that if yu just read a translation, there is no way you're walking away with what the author intended to teach.

Comment: @Gavriel and DoubleAA are unable to provide any useful suggestions. Ive since been advised a great resource called: Maimonides Life and thought. Which can be purchased here: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Maimonides-Life-Thought-Moshe-Halbertal/dp/0691165661/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1494785382&sr=8-1&keywords=maimonides+life+and+thought

Comment: @RichardLewis Feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @paquda yes linking to this question has been most useful!

Comment: As @mevaqesh suggested, you can hit that "add an answer" button at the bottom of your screen and type in which suggestions worked for you.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I actually get _a lot_ of study done in bed. :-) Besides, I don't think the OP is intending to do an in-depth study on Moreh Nevuchim, but is getting an introduction to its contents. That's why he asked for it in English. (At least, I assume that's the reason.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-guide-for-the-perplexed-moses-maimonides/1116912087?ean=9780760757574&st=PLA&sid=BNB_DRS_Core%20Shopping%20Books_00000000&2sid=Google_&sourceId=PLGoP78860) one should suffice. It is an English translation, no Hebrew, and in paperback.

Comment: That uses the poor Friedlander translation.

Comment: Please note my term "suffice." I do not believe an in-depth study can be performed on Maimonides while sitting in bed. The OP was looking for a simple, English version of Moreh Nevuchim by the Rambam. This one works for that purpose. If one wants to learn M''N for real then there are better translations and copies.

Comment: I see no advantage in using a bad translation over a good translation. Its not like its easier to read a bad translation from a century ago, in bed.